# using search * operator in combination with 'database' function

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a source database & a target database. I want to execute .append command against the target database but source tables are in the source database. I know database('SourceDB') function we can use from the target database but I don't know how to use this in combination of search *. So what I need will look something like this:-

```
.set target_table <| search database("SourceDB").* | ..some logic
```

This is not working. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: could you please clarify: (a) what "this is not working" means - specifically, what's the error message you're seeing? (b) what is the reason for you using the `search` operator - is it cause you want to copy data from multiple (all) tables into a single table? (c) are you aware that your usage of `search` operator (as shown in your question) is syntactically invalid? see docs @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/searchoperator

Comment: Basically I need to know proper syntax for using search * operator with database function -- I am explicitly using database function to specify database because I would like search * to refer to tables in a different database than the one where the query is being executed. I know how search * works , I know how database function works, the only thing I am trying to figure out is how to use both these things so that I can specify different database for search * to execute on.

Comment: the error I get is:- "Query could not be parsed" -- basically a syntax error

Comment: as far as i'm able to see, the doc i linked-to above details syntactically valid usage of the `search` operator. Moreover, i'm not sure i fully understand the reasoning behind your choice of using search - could you perhaps expand the explanation on what `... some logic does`? it's definitely possible to run cross-database queries without the `search` operator [for clarity: the reason i'm asking is that i want to try and provide you with the most-efficient solution, and not just a solution that works (perhaps, less efficiently)]

Comment: some logic is something like this:- project colA, colB, col C | distinct colA,colB,colC.  But ability to select all rows from all tables using search * is very crucial for us. Why we need that is too specific to be explained here. The doc link you provided does not explain how to use this in combination with the 'database' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would something like this work?

```
.set target_table <| union database("SourceDB").* | distinct colA, colB, colC.
```

BTW, syntax-wise - using `search` (if you still require that) could look like:

```
search in (database("SourceDB").*) "something you're searching for"
```

Comment: yes union database("sourceDB").* is exactly what I was looking for -- thanks. I can use pipe and send its output to additional transformations. But the second statement  'search in' is not useful since I can use pipe operator with this.

Comment: if it wasn't clear, i was trying to imply that you shouldn't go for `search`, unless absolutely necessary. I'm hopeful that was understood ;)